# Pandas str.contains example returns Attribute Error

Tags: python, pandas

When I try running the simplest Pandas (1.1.5) example code in:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

```
s1 = pd.Series(['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
s1.str.contains('og', regex=False)
```

And get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-0f362e40315e> in <module>
      1 s1 = pd.Series(['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
----> 2 s1.str.contains('og', regex=False)

~/apps/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     99                 )
    100                 raise TypeError(msg)
--> 101             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103         wrapper.__name__ = func_name

~/apps/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py in contains(self, pat, case, flags, na, regex)
   1108         dtype: bool
   1109         """
-> 1110         result = self._data.array._str_contains(pat, case, flags, na, regex)
   1111         return self._wrap_result(result, fill_value=na, returns_string=False)
   1112 

AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_contains'
```

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__

'1.1.5'
```

Comment: I tried this on my system and it’s working fine, albeit `0.25.1`. Perhaps a corrupted pandas installation?  Also tried successfully on `1.2.4`.

Comment: Probably somewhat related to: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40404#issuecomment-804439414. Seems like upgrading worked there, but who knows.

Comment: As suggested, indeed upgrading solved the issue. The root cause was conda downgrading pandas in the first place when I downgraded some other package. I wasn't aware of all the side effects that broke my code (such as str.contains)